# How to check my MBP's logic board properties?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, logicboard

A few days ago, my MBP had a lot of issues like multiple beeping sounds as well as black screen anomalies. The beeping issue goes away when I force a shutdown.

When I took it in for repair, they reported that there was an issue with the logic board and RAM. They replaced the logic board and the MBP was working fine.

How do I check the properties of the logic board, when it was manufactured and its condition. Again, I trust Apple support, but I just wanted to convince myself.

Is there any way to check the properties of the MBP hardware?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to truly know if something is wrong with any replacement part installed by Apple is based on symptoms of the computer and symptoms alone. Apple does have diagnostic tests they run on each computer that is repaired. That is just a stop gap to find a bad part on the way out the door. Diagnostics will never catch every problem. In other words, if the computer is not exhibiting the symptoms you brought the computer in for to begin with,  the computer (and its logic board ) are fine.

You can always run the [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) to check for yourself.